# Display external SVG with <use> tag and href or xlink:href attribute?

Tags: html, css, image, svg

The SVG is not displayed correctly when it is loaded from `<use>` element. I've added an `<img>` element after it to illustrate the expected result:

```xml
<svg>
  <use xlink:href="file.svg" href="file.svg"></use>
</svg>
<img src="file.svg" />
```

**Current output:**

[image: current output]

**Working fiddle:**
[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/0o4jtntL/57/)

Thanks to anyone who can point out my mistake.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. You have this error: *Unsafe attempt to load URL https:.....svg from frame with URL https://...... **Domains, protocols and ports must match***
2. You need to use the id of the svg object you want to use

```html
  <svg viewBox="0 0 14 16" width="50">
    <use xlink:href="sof.svg#id" fill="red"/>
  </svg>
```

Please take a look at this example: https://codepen.io/enxaneta/project/editor/91143c063e6b9abf1b5c43a14a9937ea

Answer (score 15):

The `<use>` element does *copy* an Element that you do link to from the `href` attribute. You can not point to a `file.svg` directly, you need to point to the `id` of an element.

```
<use xlink:href="path/to-the-file.svg#the-element"/>
```

```js
// since we can't store file in StackSnippets we'll download it first
fetch('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fd/Ghostscript_Tiger.svg')
.then(r => r.blob())
.then(b =>
  // and create a blobURI, with the id of a <g> Element
  use.setAttributeNS(
    'http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'href',
    URL.createObjectURL(b) + '#g4'
  )
);
```

```html
<svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 900 900">
  <use id="use"/>
</svg>
```

But note that the <image> element could also have displayed your image directly (even though you'll loose the little control you may have from <use>:

```html
<svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
  <image width="200" height="200" xlink:href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fd/Ghostscript_Tiger.svg"/>
</svg>
```

Note that while [SVG2](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/single-page.html#struct-UseElement) still has a note that they do

> relax referencing requirements to particular elements to allow dropping fragments to mean referencing root element, where it makes sense, such as with use

no browser has implemented this after 10 years, so the specs are wrong here and should be edited to remove this note, since a particular behavior should have at least two implementers to be considered "standard".

Answer (score 5):

[SVG 2](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/single-page.html#struct-UseElement) (when implemented in browsers) will allow to reference another SVG file without any [fragment identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_fragment):

> New in SVG 2: An `href` without a fragment allows an entire SVG document to be referenced without having to ensure that it has an ID on its root element.

Before:

```xml
<!-- my-vector.svg -->

<svg id="icon" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <circle r="10" cx="12" cy="12" />
</svg>
```

```xml
<use href="my-vector.svg#icon"></use>
```

After (there will be no need to define `id="..."` on the `svg`):

```xml
<!-- my-vector.svg -->

<svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <circle r="10" cx="12" cy="12" />
</svg>
```

```xml
<use href="my-vector.svg"></use>
```

SVG 2 seems to be in the process of development in major browsers (see [this Chrome feature](https://chromestatus.com/feature/5760616295825408) and specifically this Chromium issue: [Issue 366545: [SVG2] Allow  to reference entire files](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=366545)).