# SVG doesnt display while opening .html file

Tags: html, css, svg, browser

I think it is a basic problem but I haven't found solution.

Basically I created a website `(HTML,CSS,JS)`, then uploaded it to the host server via FileZilla. Everything works perfectly.

However when I downloaded the files (from the server) on a different PC, I opened `.html` file with web browser and it doesn't display SVG images. It happened few times in the past. What could be the problem? I tried using Mozilla and Edge.

```
<svg class="navigation__icons">
<use xlink:href='img/sprite.svg#logo-instagram'></use>
</svg>
```

Comment: please provide us with code so we can help you in your case =) regards,

Comment: Ah yes, sorry my bad

Comment: [Does this helps?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53794450/8134014)

Comment: Is your browser's dev tools console showing any errors?

Answer (score 0):

try to add this line as first line in your `.svg` file

```
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
```