# How to center <use> tag in CSS that is wrapped in <svg> tag

Tags: html, css, frontend

I have this piece of html:

```
<svg class="icon">
   <use href="icon.svg#icon"></use>
</svg>
```

And I need to center `<use>` tag in `<svg>` tag. `<svg>` tag has size of 20 by 20 pixels, while svg file in `<use>` tag has only 13 by 10 pixels size.
Approaches with

```
position:absolute;
top:50%;
bottom:50%;
transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
```

and

```
display: flex;
align-items: center; /* vertical alignment */
justify-content: center;
```

for `<use>` tag are not working for me

[element looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PK561.png)

update:
I kinda figured it out, but I can't get why it works that way.
When I set `width` and `height` properties for `<svg>` tag, `<use>` tag moves from the center to the top left of `<svg>` element

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Display external SVG with <use> tag and href or xlink:href attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53794292/display-external-svg-with-use-tag-and-href-or-xlinkhref-attribute)

Comment: @BumhanYu, no, svg renders properly it is just not centered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your icon in a `<symbol>` and add suitable `viewBox` attribute (e.g . viewBox="0 0 13 10").

Your `<use>` instance will be centered within the parent `<svg>` element.

```html
<svg style="border:1px solid red; height:200px" viewBox="0 0 200 100">
  <use href="#home" />
</svg>

<svg style="border:1px solid red; height:200px; width:200px">
  <use href="#home" />
</svg>

<svg style="border:1px solid red; height:200px" viewBox="0 0 10 40">
  <use href="#home" />
</svg>

<!-- hidden svg asset to emulate external icon reference -->
<svg style="width:0; height:0;">
<symbol id="home" viewBox="0 0 34 48">
<path d="M33.16,28.12h-5.2v13h-3.44v-16.72l-7.72-8.72l-7.72,8.72v16.72h-3.44v-13h-5.24l16.4-17.4Z" />
 </symbol>
</svg>
```

#### Calculate `viewBox`

You can either calculate a minimal/cropped `viewBox`based on the actual boundaries or a rather "rounded up" and centered one.
Both examples use `getBBox()` to get the bounding box of an svg element.

```js
let bb = path.getBBox();
let [x,y,width,height] =[bb.x, bb.y, bb.width, bb.height];
//svg.setAttribute('viewBox', [x,y,width,height].join(' '));

setAutoViewBox(path)
setAutoViewBoxMin(path2)

function setAutoViewBoxMin(el){
  let svg = el.closest('svg');
  let bb = path.getBBox();
  let [x,y,width,height] =[bb.x, bb.y, bb.width, bb.height];
  // set smallest viewBox: cropped to the exact boundaries 
  let newViewBox = [x,y,width,height];
  svg.setAttribute('viewBox', newViewBox.join(' '));
}


function setAutoViewBox(el){
  let svg = el.closest('svg');
  let bb = path.getBBox();
  let [x,y,width,height] =[bb.x, bb.y, bb.width, bb.height];
  // set centered viewBox by adding x and y values to calculated width/height
  let newViewBox = [0,0,width+x*2,height+y*2].map(val=>{ return Math.ceil(val)});
  svg.setAttribute('viewBox', newViewBox.join(' '));
}
```

```css
svg{
  height:30em;
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<p>Centered</p>
<svg id="svg">
<path id="path" d="M33.16,28.12h-5.2v13h-3.44v-16.72l-7.72-8.72l-7.72,8.72v16.72h-3.44v-13h-5.24l16.4-17.4Z" />
</svg>

<p>Cropped</p>
<svg id="svg2">
<path id="path2" d="M33.16,28.12h-5.2v13h-3.44v-16.72l-7.72-8.72l-7.72,8.72v16.72h-3.44v-13h-5.24l16.4-17.4Z" />
</svg>

<p>Original</p>
<svg id="home" viewBox="0 0 34 48">
<path d="M33.16,28.12h-5.2v13h-3.44v-16.72l-7.72-8.72l-7.72,8.72v16.72h-3.44v-13h-5.24l16.4-17.4Z" />
 </svg>
```

Comment: can I somehow get width and height of the `path` or size of `use` tag to set height and width of `viewbox` to it, in case i won't know actual size?

Comment: Sure, you can check it via `path.getBBox()` method. See new example.

Answer (score 0):

You must stablish width property to USE tag, also I think you are overthinking the center property in SVG tag.

Read this article for a very simple use of Flex in css

[Article in coryrylan](https://coryrylan.com/blog/how-to-center-in-css-with-flexbox)